# When is `T *restrict`'s no-aliasing guarantee enforced?

Tags: c, null, restrict-qualifier

If I have an aliasing `T *restrict`, but it is never used, is this considered undefined-behavior. Or is undefined behavior at the point of use.

For example

```c
int *nothing = NULL;
int *restrict also_nothing = NULL;
```

Here I have two unused pointers both `NULL`. However, one of them is `restrict`... Is this not technically UB?

Finally, doesn't this effectively mean that `T *restrict`s are practically speaking never `NULL`?

Comment: What do you think `restrict` means? Setting a `restrict`-qualified pointer to a null pointer value does not violate its requirements. Never using a `restrict`-qualified pointer does not violate its requirements. Essentially all `restrict` means is that if an object is accessed through the pointer (directly or indirectly) and is modified by any means, then every access to the object during the lifetime of the pointer shall be through the pointer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah, I thought that `restrict` meant `noalias`.

Comment: `noalias` here means not pointing to the same object. But a `NULL` pointer doesn't point to any object at all. So that would be fine.

Comment: @BoP If you answer this, and include Eric's point about the point-of-use being the issue, I would accept the answer.